# How to disable the map rotation feature in the Android Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I use the [Google Maps Api Version 2 for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)to add a MapFragment to my Application.

This Fragments improves a lot in terms of speed and API usability. Sadly it also allows to rotate the map with a two finger gesture. I want to disable the rotation because this two finger gesture is often recognized instead of the gesture for zooming.

How can I disable the map rotation?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It turned out to be straight forward if you look into the right place in documentation.

There is a [UiSettings](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings) class inside a GoogleMap that allows enabling and disabling of gestures.

```
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
  GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();
  map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: You should accept your answer -- or delete the question, as it's even shown in the Demo-App how to turn all those features on and off...

Comment: I also tried to find disabling zoom buttons and I found it in getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your Google Map with code like this:

```
GoogleMapOptions googleMapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
...
mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(googleMapOptions);
```

Then you can also disable the rotation gesture like this:

```
GoogleMapOptions googleMapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
...
googleMapOptions.rotateGesturesEnabled(false);
mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(googleMapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

and in onmapReady insert this :

`mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);`